# How do I asynchronously run reports in .NET?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, reportviewer

I have a form with a grid.  The grid has a context menu and one of the menu items should create reports for each item selected in the grid.  However, I'd like the reports to run on a separate thread and for the context menu to close almost immediately after clicking on the report item.  I'm still trying to understand this whole threading thing.  Below is what I have so far.  Here is what is happening.  When I click on the context menu item, the context menu shows up, then the first report comes up, a pause, then the second report comes up, a pause, etc.  However, the context menu doesn't go away until the last report is shown.  I'm not real worried about the pauses between the reports but it does look like they're being processed synchronously.  I mainly want to know why the context menu doesn't go away immediately.

```
void custodyRptItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (CustodyItem curItem in CustodyControl.SelectedItems)
  {             
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ShowReportDelegate)ShowChainOfCustodyReport, curItem);
  }
}

void ShowChainOfCustodyReport(CustodyItem item)
{
   CustodyReport report = new CustodyReport(item);
   report.Show();
}
```

Comment: No threads are being created here, ShowChainOfCustodyReport() runs on the UI thread.  Which is okay, it is very unlikely that it will work properly when you actually create a thread.

Answer (score 0):

"If multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority, they will be executed in the order the calls were made." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx

Even though BeginInvoke returns immediately, all the delegates are executed on the thread the Dispatcher was created on, and therefore they are executed synchronously (in respect to each other).

I assume the Dispatcher is from the GUI thread and that is why the context menu doesn't disappear until all the report forms have shown - the message pump handles the messages about executing your ShowChainOfCustodyReport before the message to make the menu disappear. Btw, it is good that ShowChainOfCustodyReport is being called on the GUI thread since you don't want to call report.Show() on the non-GUI thread or at least a thread without a message pump.

Is the only reason you want to do this "asynchronously" is so the menu disappears before the reports show up? Have you tried calling Hide() on the context menu before your Dispatcher.Invoke() (not sure this is possible, haven't worked with context menus in a while...). If this does work, you can probably remove all the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke code and just call report.Show() directly since Show() is not blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You may use TreadPool for that:

```
    void custodyRptItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (CustodyItem curItem in CustodyControl.SelectedItems)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ShowChainOfCustodyReport, curItem);
        }
    }

    void ShowChainOfCustodyReport(object context)
    {
        CustodyItem item = context as CustodyItem;
        if (item == null) return;

        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<object> a = ShowChainOfCustodyReport;
            Invoke(a, context);
        }
        else
        {
            CustodyReport report = new CustodyReport(item);
            report.Show();
        }
    }
```